# Make the statements (if, try) shorter

Tags: python, refactoring, command-line-arguments

I have following code blocks at the beginning of the script:

```
try:
    sys.argv[3]
except Exception:
    print(use)
    sys.exit()

if int(sys.argv[2]) > 4:
    print 'works'
    sys.exit()
else:
    print(use)
    sys.exit()
```

I do checks but as you can see it doesn't look pretty, because part "print(use); sys.exit()" is repeated. Is there any way to reach it shorter and more beautiful?

Comment: That's not a quesiton about performance.

Comment: Use `argparse`…?

Comment: `int(sys.argv[2])` can crash if the value isn't an integer you didn't protect against that.

Comment: You can't really factorize : The first sys.exit() should be a `raise` (i.e. re-raise the exception). The second one is ok to be a sys.exit(). The third should be a `raise ValueError("args[2] must be >4")`

Answer (score 2):

You get all of that functionality for free using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError

def greater_than_4(string):
    value = int(string)
    if value <= 4:
        raise ArgumentTypeError('%r must be greater than 4' % string)
    return value

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('first', type=greater_than_4)
parser.add_argument('second')
args = parser.parse_args()

print 'works'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
try:
    sys.argv[3]
    if int(sys.argv[2]) > 4:
        print 'works'
    else
        raise ValueException("Incorrect parameter passed")
except Exception:
    print(use)
finally:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function for that:

```
def report_and_quit(message=''):
    print(message)
    sys.exit()
```

and then you can do:

```
try:
    sys.argv[3]
except Exception:
    report_and_quit(use)

if int(sys.argv[2]) > 4:
    report_and_quit('works')
else:
    report_and_quit(use)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    x = int(sys.argv[2])
    assert x > 4
    y = sys.argv[3]
except Exception:
    print(use)
    sys.exit()

print('works')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def tmp(use):
    print(use)
    sys.exit()

try:
    sys.argv[3]
except Exception:
    tmp(use)

if int(sys.argv[2]) > 4:
    print 'works'
    sys.exit()
else:
    tmp(use)
```